# Stack Empty exception on HTMLWorker in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using this code to mail a datatable in the form of a pdf. But on converting the data using html parser, it is showing the exception as Stack Empty. However I have done this before and it worked, I just cant put my finger on what am I missing now. Please help!!!!!

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");


            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                //sb.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>");
                sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
                sb.Append("</th>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(row[column]);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
            sb.Append("</table>");


        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();                    
                htmlparser.Parse(sr);//here is the error
                pdfDoc.Close();
                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();

                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), email.Trim());
                mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text.Trim();
                //mm.CC.Add = txtcc.Text.Trim();
                mm.Body = txtBody.Text.Trim();
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "iTextSharpPDF.pdf"));
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
                NetworkCred.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Send(mm);
            }
```

}
}

Comment: what is sr variable. If it is a HTML string then put a breakpoint on that line. And copy the HTML string and run some online html parser tool and check where is error. It looks like there is an issue in HTML string.

Comment: StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);   sr is the string reader and sb is the string builder

Comment: are you getting your html in string builder means `sb.ToString()` from html file or you build your html as hard coded in your program?

Comment: getting html in string builder

Comment: could u please add your string builder code in post ?

Comment: added the whole code alongwith the string builder.

Comment: None of the code you've posted rethrows an exception in a way that wouldn't preserve the stack-trace for all circumstances (i.e. your `using` blocks). Instead I suspect your environment places restrictions on the debugger or your debugger is incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 2):

1) Make you changes like below while building your `html` via `StringBuilder` like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//Open table
sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");

//Open first tr for all of th
sb.Append("<tr>");
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
     sb.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>");
     sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
     sb.Append("</th>");
}

//Close first tr for all of th
sb.Append("</tr>");


foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{   
    //Open tr for all of rows
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append("<td>");
        sb.Append(row[column]);
        sb.Append("</td>");
    }

    //Close tr for all of rows
    sb.Append("</tr>");
}


//Close table
sb.Append("</table>");
```

2) Use `XMLWorkerHelper` instead of `HTMLWorker` because now `HTMLWorker` is deprecated. and not more support by `iTextSharp`. like

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
memoryStream.Close();
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823539/stack-empty-error-when-using-itextsharp-for-converting-html-to-pdf)

Try once may it help you.

Comment: @Tanvi Dutta, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: @Tanvi Dutta, if answer was helpful to you then accept it or let me know if you have any issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing openning tags, that's why component throws exception, since it reads closing tags which were not opened and stack is empty (probably it uses stack to track openning/closing tags):

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");    

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<th>");
                sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
                sb.Append("</th>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(row[column]);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
            sb.Append("</table>");
```